# Jasmine with Karma: Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

### Issue

I am running Javascript tests using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) and [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/)(As a test runner). The issue is that `Ajax` requests do not seam to be working.

If I run the following Jasmine test with Karma:

```
describe("Tests Ajax", function(done){
    it("does not work", function(){
        var options = {
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "complete": function(data){
                console.log("Done!");
                done();
            }
        };

        $.ajax(options);
    });
});
```

I get the following Karma error:

```
        PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8) Tests Ajax does not work FAILED
            Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified
            by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

This means that the test took to long. I have tried setting `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` to a longer time in `beforeEach` but this does not seam to change the results.

If I then run the above Ajax code in my browser it works and outputs "Done!" almost immediately.

The above results lead me to conclude that for some reason Ajax requests do not work when running Jasmine tests with Karma.

### Additional Information

**OS**: Windows 8
**Karma Test Browsers**: PhantomJS(I have also tested with IE, Chrome, ChromeCanary, and Firefox, result are the same)
**Karma Version**: 0.12.31
**Karma Jasmine Version**: 0.3.2

[Karma Config File](http://pastebin.com/2yYMgMVn)
[Github Repo](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/NoahHuppert.com/tree/ts-test-suite)

I am choosing not to use [Jasmine Ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) because the code I am testing involves putting together various Ajax `options` correctly based on many other conditions and then interpreting the results. Thus completing a real Ajax request(To local files) is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around this issue I decided to run my tests with [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) and have a server running in the background serving my content.

I used [grunt-http-server](https://github.com/aetheon/grunt-http-server) for the server. I ran into 2 issues when setting this up. The first was that by default `grunt-http-server` does not allow Cross Origin Requests. To allow them you must add a `headers` option to the grunt task setup with the following headers:

```
{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
}
```

The second issue I had was that `grunt-http-server` returns data no in the `body` field but in the `responseText` or `responseJSON` fields.

Comment: responseText sounds like the right field to me. I had a similar issue and it was due to CORS not accepting the request -- is your onError method getting called? That should tell you where the error is occurring.